# How to compare between dictionary value and pandas data frame?

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

So, I have dataframe like this, imported from csv file

| name | math | physic |
| --- | --- | --- |
| James | 80 | 90 |
| Tom | 60 | 70 |
| Jerry | 90 | 60 |

and I have a dictionary

```
data = {'math': 60, 'physic': 70}
```

I want to check for every value of data dict and compare it with data frame. If the matching value of math and physic it should return the name. In this case `Tom`.

How can I do this? Any suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `boolean indexing` with `loc`:

```
df.loc[df[data].eq(data.values()).all(1), 'name']
```

---

```
1    Tom
Name: name, dtype: object
```

Comment: It works!. But, how if I just want to return 'Tom'?

Comment: Check `tolist` like `df.loc[df[data].eq(data.values()).all(1), 'name'].tolist()`

Answer (score 0):

Usually find operation is not so efficient in pandas and numpy but that would do:

```
df[(df['math'] == mydict['math'] )& (df['physic'] == mydict['physic'] )]['name'][0]
'Tom'
```

Comment: it returns to invalid syntax

Comment: How come? Whatbin this syntax is invalid im curious...

Answer (score 0):

return the intersection of data and DataFrame:

```py
df_str = '''
name    math    physic
James   80  90
Tom 60  70
Jerry   90  60
'''
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(df_str.strip()), sep='\s+', index_col=False)

data = {'math': 60, 'physic': 70}
def query_name(data):
    df2 = pd.Series(data).to_frame().T
    dfn = pd.merge(df, df2, on=['math', 'physic'], how='inner')
    return dfn

data = {'math': 90, 'physic': 60}
query_name(data)
```

```
['Jerry']
```

Comment: "No common columns to perform merge on. "
pandas.errors.MergeError: No common columns to perform merge on. Merge options: left_on=None, right_on=None, left_index=False, right_index=False

Comment: The `data` keys should be in `df.columns`. Update with df definition.

Comment: File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/merge.py", line 87, in merge
    validate=validate,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/merge.py", line 652, in __init__
    ) = self._get_merge_keys()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/merge.py", line 1018, in _get_merge_keys
    left_keys.append(left._get_label_or_level_values(lk))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 1563, in _get_label_or_level_values
    raise KeyError(key)